# Karma Jasmin how to update the window href

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage

I want to update the window href location while jasmine open the browser

e.g localhost:9876/conrtext.html?language=en

please let me know if any one has implemented such type of scenario

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why you want update? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to test with different languages by passing the param in window href location

e.g localhost:9876/conrtext.html?language=hi